# LINQ query works agains SQL Server but not Entity Framework/LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a LINQ query which works fine when I test it in LINQPad agains my SQL Server database, however when I test it against my Entity Framework context (which is required in my LightSwitch .NET app) it gives an error that .First() must be user as a final operation.

```
Table.Where(re => !re.UserSave.HasValue || re.UserSave == INT PARAMETER)
     .GroupBy(re => re.UniqueKey)
     .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserSave.HasValue) ?? g.First())
```

It suggest that using FirstOrDefault() instead, but since i call First() only if FirstOrDefault() returns false I have no idea how to get around this problem.

```
NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`:

```
Table.Where(re => !re.UserSave.HasValue || re.UserSave == INT PARAMETER)
     .GroupBy(re => re.UniqueKey)
     .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserSave.HasValue) ?? g.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: That totally works, thanks! Why didn't i try that, I feel stupid. Still, it makes no sense at all why First() wouldn't work..

Comment: Because `First` requires an exception when no results were fetched.